# пакет camera на секунду возникает ошибка The getter 'value' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

**Описание ошибки**
======== Exception caught by widgets library
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building MyHomePage(dirty, state: _MyHomePageState#ef271):
The getter 'value' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: value
The relevant error-causing widget was:
MyHomePage file:///D:/project/flutter/f1/lib/main.dart:20:11
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0 Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1 _MyHomePageState.build (package:f1/main.dart:80:25)
#2 StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4744:28)
#3 ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4627:15)
#4 StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4800:11)

**Красный экран ошибки возникает на секунду**, затем все нормально
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

далее, полный код
***main.dart***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 CameraController _cameraController;

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _funInitialization();

 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  _cameraController.dispose();

 }

 void _f1() {
  setState(() {

  });
 }

 Future<void> _funInitialization() async {

  List<CameraDescription> cameras = await availableCameras();

  _cameraController = CameraController(
   cameras[0],
   ResolutionPreset.max
  )..initialize().then((_) {
   if (!mounted) {
    return;
   }
   setState(() {});
  });

 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  if(!_cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
   return Container();
  }

  return Stack(
   children: [
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.center,
     /*child: AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 3 / 4,
      child: CameraPreview(_cameraController),
     ),*/
     child: Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: CameraPreview(_cameraController),
     ),
    ),
   ],
  );

 }

}
```

Comment: `didChangeAppLifecycleState` - где? `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` - где? Сделай по оф.документации пакета camera, думаю что "проблема" этим решится.

Comment: Уважаемый yar85, огромное Вам спасибо. didChangeAppLifecycleState еще не использовал, а вот WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); использовал. Ошибки больше нет. Оформите Ваш комментарий, как ответ, что бы можно было засчиать.

Comment: Добавил еще чуток информации - раз уж писать ответ)) Насчет `didChangeAppLifecycleState` - не факт что относится к данной проблеме: т.е. если я верно понимаю доки, это относится к правильной обработке ситуаций изменения состояния приложения, типа "перешел на хоумскрин - вернулся в приложение - бац, ошибка"... а тут другой случай. Другими словами: добавить обработчик в код будет не лишним (на всякий пожарный), но вот в ответе это похоже будет лишней инфой (логика "разные проблемы - разные решения").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала, стоит посмотреть на происхождение ошибки.
В ее stacktrace мы видим строку, говорящую нам что ошибка произошла в билдер-функции класса `_MyHomePageState` - это предпоследний элемент стека вызовов:

```
#1 _MyHomePageState.build (package:f1/main.dart:80:25)
```

, и если поищем в коде этой функции обращения к свойству `value`, то даже без прохода отладчиком тут можем легко определить: ошибка вызвана тем что значение `_cameraController` при запуске по факту является `null` (об этом нам говорит текст ошибки).

То есть, метод `build` обращается к переменной экземпляра контроллера **до того**, как эта переменная инициализирована значением. Отсюда и ошибка, которая сохраняется пока не выполнится перерисовка уже после инициализации.

---

**В качестве решения**, обхода этой неприятной ситуации, мы можем добавить перед вызовом `runApp` следующее выражение:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

- это принудительно инициализирует программный слой между виджетами и движком Flutter, но только если такая инициализация требуется.
 *<sub>// И на самом деле, эта строчка решает множество похожих проблем при запуске приложения - а не только с данным пакетом и в данном случае.</sub>*

Делать так рекомендует и оф. документация пакета camera. Вот фрагмент примера из нее:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

List<CameraDescription> cameras;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();   // ◄◄◄

  cameras = await availableCameras();
  runApp(CameraApp());
}

/* .... */
```

Хочется сразу внести ясность: такая явная инициализация рекомендуется флаттером *"**только** при необходимости в биндинге до вызова `runApp`"*.
Тем не менеe, ее можно выполнять и для подстраховки - это не наносит какого-либо вреда, насколько мне известно. То есть, не страшно вызывать этот метод инициализации и просто когда нет уверенности в порядке подготовки объектов (от его внешних зависимостей, особенно). В этом есть смысл просто для гарантии того, что в момент запуска приложения, биндинг виджетов к движку уже будет готов работать.